# Saving a .xlsx file to ec2, getting an empty file in response

Tags: python-3.x, flask, openpyxl

The new file saved at the end of the code is just empty, need some assist here, Using in a flask api on ec2 linux server

from openpyxl import load_workbook

```
    name = 'somebrandname'
    country = 'someCountry'
    url = 'someUrl'
    
    
    xfile = load_workbook(existing_file_name)

 
    sheet = xfile.get_sheet_by_name('Media Plan - Online')
    sheet['C3'].value = name
    sheet['C5'].value = url
    sheet['C11'].value = country

    xfile.save('MediaPlan.xlsx') #new file to be saved with changes
    xfile.close()
```

Comment: Could you provide use with an example snippet of the workbook that you are loading?

Comment: @Thymen Its working on my local windows server but when I push the changes on the ec2 linux  server the code saves an empty file.

Comment: Then probably you have a path error, verify that the data can be located on the ec2 Linux server. But without any more details we cannot help you.

Comment: I changed the path to (f"{app.root_path}/{file_name}") still same Issue

Comment: It was fixed actually I was creating an empty file with the function I was handling the download file option and not using the already stored fuile